# GoRouter.of(context).routeInformationProvider.value.uri does not return the correct route when calling pop()

Tags: flutter-go-router

I am using go_router: ^12.1.3 with my Flutter mobile app, and to get the current route, I am calling:

```
final uri = GoRouter.of(context).routeInformationProvider.value.uri
```

However I noticed that when calling context.pop(), the returned uri is not correct. The return uri is only correct if I call context.go() or context.goNamed(). Is there an explanation for that?